# Multiprocessing and Data Synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, multiprocessing

First off, I am brand new to the multiprocessing and threading world. I have two devices that generate data (gps and mca). the gps simulator is supposed to generate a location every 0.1 seconds. The mca is supposed to generate a random number every randomly generated time interval. When an event is registered by the mca, the count (cnt) is supposed to be sent to the count list.The same goes for the gps. The event handler is supposed to synchronize the count with the latest gps value is registered, and this should be printed to standard output. After 5 seconds, the mca should stop and send 'DONE' over a Queue to stop all of the other functions.I am also very new to Queue. It seems to me that my definitions start but don't do anything.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could fix my code or let me know what is going wrong in it.

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep, time, clock

count = []
gps_data = []

def mca(q1):
    print 'started'
    t = 5
    while True:
        cnt = random.randint(0,30)
        count.append(cnt)
        dt = random.randint(0,3)
        sleep(dt)
        nt = t-dt
        if nt <= 0:
            break
    q1.put('DONE')

def gps(q1):
    print 'started2'
    while q1.get() != 'DONE':
        x = 0
        dt = 0.1
        sleep(dt)
        y = x + 1
        gps_data.append(y)

def event_handler(q1):
    print 'started3'
    size_i = len(count)          #initial size of the mca list
    while q1.get() != 'DONE':
        size_f = len(count)
        if size_f > size_i:
            local_count = count[-1]
            local_location = gps_data[-1]
            data = local_count + local_location
            print str(data)
            size_i = size_f
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q1 = Queue()
    p_mca = Process(target = mca, args = (q1,))
    p_gps = Process(target = gps, args = (q1,))
    p_evh = Process(target = event_handler, args = (q1,))

    p_evh.start()
    p_gps.start()
    p_mca.start()

    p_evh.join()
    p_gps.join()
    p_mca.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable *t* in mca() keeps getting set back to 5, thus

```
if nt <= 0:
```

is never True.

Answer (score 0):

Like D_rez90 said,

```
if nt<=0:
```

is never true. You should change

```
nt=t-dt
```

to

```
t-=dt
if t<=0:
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix the problem.In the event handler function, the data is supposed to be printed to standard output, but nothing happens. This is all I get: started3, started2, started. And then the program just sits there, and does not stop, or do anything else.